# Should this question closed as "not constructive" be re-opened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, question-closure

[Why are “put” and “but” different in their pronunciation? [closed]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105081/why-are-put-and-but-different-in-their-pronunciation?lq=1)

I was editing my answer to a very similar question here: [Why there is difference in pronunciation of words PUT and CUT?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254455/why-there-is-difference-in-pronunciation-of-words-put-and-cut/254506#254506) In fact, I think these questions should be merged. But I also think that the merged question should be re-opened, in case someone in the future has more useful information about this topic. Please post an answer explaining what you think.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

The question is basically about the historical development of one part of the English language. It has a real answer supported by facts and not opinion; read [Jon Hanna's post](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105092/77227) to see what it is.